# What is the best evaluation of training the sequential modeling?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, nonlinear-regression, overfitting, recurrent-neural-network

It's concerned with the probabilistic modeling of the sequential dataset.
As far as my understanding, well-known RNN methodologies consist of two steps:

1. firstly, train the model representing $p(y_{i}|y_{i-1})$ 
   with respect to the loss calculated from the pair of consecutive samples $(y_{i-1}, y_{i})$,
2. and then, consequently obtain $p(y_{N}, \cdots y_{1}|y_{0}) = p(y_{N}|y_{N-1})\cdots p(y_{1}|y_{0})$
   given a sequence $(y_{0}, y_{1}, \cdots, y_{N})$.

However, there can be another option for training:

1. sample any sequence from the dataset: $(y_{0}, y_{1}, \cdots, y_{N})$
2. and then train $p(y_{i}|y_{i-1})$ with respect to the loss evaluating $p(y_{N}, \cdots y_{1}|y_{0}) = p(y_{N}|y_{N-1})\cdots p(y_{1}|y_{0})$
   (e.g. logarithm likelihood, Wasserstein distance, etc.).

Those two methods train a recurrent unit $p(y_{i}|y_{i-1})$ and the loss function is theoretically the same thing.

- Is there any difference between them in the practical sense?
- For example, the latter can reduce the over-fitting?,
- the latter can be better at long-term prediction, but not at short-term one?etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a bit confused, because an RNN does not model $p(y_i | y_{i-1})$ -- indeed, in most cases, such a simple conditional probability could be modeled just by constructing a large frequency-count table.

In general, an RNN defines a distribution $p(y) = \prod_j p(y_i | y_{j<i})$. In most cases, you train by directly maximizing log-likelihood of entire sequences from the dataset.

Comment: I think there was a minor LaTeX typo that I've fixed. If I'm wrong, please rollback with my apologies.